# dart timer periodic documentation is confusing

Tags: dart

I have a long running task and I would like to schedule a new run a fixed interval after the run ends and I found this.  What does the following mean? In particular the last paragraph.

> Timer.periodic(Duration duration, Function void callback(Timer timer))
>
> Creates a new repeating timer.
>
> The callback is invoked repeatedly with duration intervals until
>   canceled with the cancel function.
>
> The exact timing depends on the underlying timer implementation. No
>   more than n callbacks will be made in duration * n time, but the time
>   between two consecutive callbacks can be shorter and longer than
>   duration.
>
> In particular, an implementation may schedule the next callback, e.g.,
>   a duration after either when the previous callback ended, when the
>   previous callback started, or when the previous callback was scheduled
>   for - even if the actual callback was delayed.

Comment: It says that the callback will be called periodically no matter what state the previous is in.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you set a timer to run every 30 seconds. If the second time the callback is called it takes 10 seconds to complete, the third call to the callback could be:

- 30 seconds after the second call started
- 30 seconds after the second call ended (which is 40s after the second call started, since it took 10 secs)
- 30 seconds after the second call was scheduled to run (which based on the above, could have been delayed, eg. by the duration of the first call)

Comment: It is the work 'Could' that is the issue. So on different systems it will have different behaviours which is very confusing.

Comment: That's correct. The exact details are left to the implementation, though "No more than n callbacks will be made in duration * n time". It should be fine for most things (eg. poll this approx every x minutes), but isn't intended as an accurate timer.

Comment: Based on what the documentation says, in cases where higher than typical accuracy is desired, it may be helpful to encase the code run in the callback in an `async` lambda, i.e., `Timer.periodic(duration,(){ ()async{ code_to_run; }() });` Although it may still be inaccurate, as the documentation only gives an example and not necessarily every case of inaccuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Timer's duration is delay. Timer.periodic's duration is period.